# How can I convert a date into another format with moment.js?

Tags: jquery, date, momentjs

I try to convert my date into another date with moment.js (https://momentjs.com/)

```
var date = "05.06.2020 10:46";
var DateCreated = moment(date, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM').format('Y-m-d');
```

But the output is "invalid Date".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var DateCreated = moment(date, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM').format('Y-m-d');`

Don't you need `HH:mm` small `m` for minutes? 46 won't match any month, and that is your problem :)

Comment: the solution is `var DateCreated = moment(cellData, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm').format('YY-MM-DD');`

Comment: `format('Y-m-d')` did worked, although, the output does not make any real sense :)